# add custom product statuses in opencart admin

Tags: opencart, product, status

By default in opencart we have 2 product statuses (which we can use also in admin to filter products) - enabled and disabled.

I need to add a few more custom statuses, which will be just for my team which is working over the products (for example i want to add `need description` status, products with the custom statuses will not show in the front end (like disabled) so if the product is market with it, the team who is working on product descriptions will easy filter only the products that need descriptions).

I hope i explained clearly as well...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the language file of product admin/language/language_name/catalog/product.php, there is $_['text_enabled'] and $_['text_disabled'], you can add $_['text_need_description'].

In category.php and product.php controllers you will find

```
$data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
$data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
```

Next to them, you can add

```
$data['text_need_description'] = $this->language->get('text_need_description');
```

You can check occurrences of 'enabled' and change accordingly. You also need to change the relevant templates and models.

In database, status is saved as 1 for enabled and 0 for disabled, you can save the value 2 for 'need description'.

When the products are fetched to be displayed to the customer on front-end, only the products with status 1 are fetched so you won't have to change that part.

Comment: Im not pretty sure that i will success alone, but i will give a try, this sounds like exactly what i need

Comment: Reach me if you need any help

Comment: What i must change in models and do i need to change anything in the databases?

Comment: Just recheck if you have to change models, because i just checked that it saves value that is passed from the form so you won't have to change models or database

Comment: I think same like you, dont need to change any query its taking just `status`

Comment: Yeah, not 'stock_status_id' though, just the 'status' field.

Comment: Just i need to edit the tpl and to show new statuses in the dropdown, so the products will be filterable

Comment: yeah, just like enabled and disabled in the dropdown